# How do I predict the residuals vs predicted graphs to choose a model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to figure out if my model from lmer follows the assumptions. The graph that O get for standardized residuals vs. fitted is attached. I am not sure what it means.

This is the model

```
lm1_1 <- lmer(BA_subplot_hectare~Treatment+Block+(1|Plot),data=ST_all_data)
```

[image]